# "What does "I believe will soon be on the forefront of modern marketing tactics" mean?

Tags: grammar

I found that sentence when I googling.
"Your company offers several marketing packages that I believe will soon be on the forefront of modern marketing tactics."

Now I'm trying to understand in especially,

> "I believe will soon be".

I understand that sentence like this " I believe  I will soon be ~" am I right to understand?

I want to know some usage of that phrase and how to remove "I" in grammatically.

How can I understand the meaning and grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I set off **I believe** with a pair of commas, do you think the sentence will become clearer for you?

> Your company offers several marketing packages that, I believe, will soon be on the forefront of modern marketing tactics.

**I believe** there is nothing more than a kind of parenthetical statement expressing the speaker's opinion as to what he or she thinks will happen to those marketing packages they're talking about: he or she believes that they will soon be on the forefront of modern marketing tactics. We can actually get rid of it completely without affecting the semantics of the sentence:

> Your company offers several marketing packages that will soon be on the forefront of modern marketing tactics.

Comment: I can understand more clearer than before. how can I get that kind of ability such as you set a pair of commas. I didn't think of that. wonderful!

Comment: The only thing that I can say is that it all comes with practice.